# JQuery, помогите разобрать код

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Люди добрые, помогите пожалуйста понять что творится в данном коде, а точнее в верхней его части, где находится **.post**. Что значит то что в скобочках после него, и как это дальше взаимодействует? Заранее спасибо)

```
function reloadMessages(){
            $.post('core.php',{action:'getMessages',search:$('.searchInp').val()}, function(data){
                obj = $.parseJSON(data);

                html = '';
                    for(i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
                        mes = obj[i];
                        html += '<p>';
                        html += mes.login;
                        html += '[' + mes.messageTime+']';
                        html += ':' + mes.message;
                        html += ' <button data-id = "'+mes.id+'" class = "delBth">Delete</button>';
                        html += ' <button data-id = "'+mes.id+'" class = "updateBth">Update</button>';
                        html += '</p>';
                    }
                $('.messageList').html(html);

                $('.delBth').click(function(){
                    id = $(this).data('id');
                    data = {
                        action:'delete',
                        id:id
                    }
                    $.post('core.php',data,function(){
                        reloadMessages();
                        $('.deleteWIn').html('deleted');
                    });
                });
                //console.log(data);
                //console.log(obj);
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть документация, читайте:

Оригинал: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Русский вариант: [http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_запрос_методом_POST](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC_POST)